# RXJS modify order of subscribers

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Is it possible to ensure that a subscriber is the last to be executed in the observer queue? A `delay(0)` is no option for me since I need the code to be executed in line and not asynchrounus.

```
let observable = new Subject<void>();

//delay(0) no option!
observable.pipe().subscribe(() => console.log("I want to be last!"));
observable.subscribe(() => console.log("I want to be first!"));

observable.next();
```

I've created an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-demo-xuf2ru

I want the first subscriber, to be executed last. The current console output is:

> I want to be last!
>
> I want to be first!

Comment: Why do you care? If you have an issue with this, it hints at deeper problems. Subscribers should be independent.

Comment: I need to call Angular's cdr after all events have been published. I can either call it after I call the subject or, what I think is way nicer, after the subject was invoked.

But since it's not cdr specific I did not mention it for not confusing unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use a common *Subject* as a means of communication between the observables as illustrated below:

```
const observable = new Subject<void>();
const commonSub$ = new Subject();

observable.pipe().subscribe(() => {
  commonSub$
    .subscribe(() => {
      console.log('I want to be last!');
    });
});

observable.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('I want to be first!');
  commonSub$.next(true);
});

observable.next();
```

Thereby, only after the second message is logged the first message will be logged.

---

As per your latest comment, you may use *switchMap* to ensure the same functionality is achieved for multiple events:

```
observable
   .switchMap(() => {
      return commonSub$;
   })
   .subscribe(() => {
      console.log("I want to be last!");
   });

observable.subscribe(() => {
   console.log("I want to be first!");
   commonSub$.next(true);
});
```

Comment: Can you modify this to even work property with multiple events? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-demo-nf24yq

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 observables with the desired output and then use the mergeMap operator to preserve the order.

```
const observable1 = Observable.of("I want to be first!");
const observable2 = Observable.of("I want to be last!");

observable1
  .mergeMap(x => {
    console.log(x);
    return observable2;
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-demo-khwrco)

Comment: I like your idea but can't get it working. I modified it a bit to illustrate my problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-demo-q6cuxq

I need "observable1" to be called many times (it is used as an external event). Now after all the subscribers are called I need to run my internal code.